# I have a problem after Java to Kotlin conversion with the error in Android Studio, Cannot infer a type for this parameter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, fetch2

As I converted this method in Java:

```
private void enqueueDownloads() {
    final List<Request> requests = Data.getFetchRequestWithGroupId(GROUP_ID);
    fetch.enqueue(requests, updatedRequests -> {

    }, error -> Timber.d("DownloadListActivity Error: %1$s", error.toString()));

}
```

It led to this method which has a lot of errors:

```
private fun enqueueDownloads() {
    val requests = Data.getFetchRequestWithGroupId(GROUP_ID)
    fetch.enqueue(requests, { updatedRequests ->

    }, { error -> Timber.d("DownloadListActivity Error: %1\$s", error.toString()) })

}
```

This method in Kotlin has a lot of errors at the method `fetch.enqueue` where the value `updatedRequests`and `error` it says `Cannot infer a type for this parameter`.

So I hit hover on the method and hit `Ctrl+B` and the method declaration in the library is:

```
fun enqueue(requests: List<Request>, func: Func<List<Request>>? = null, func2: Func<Error>? = null): Fetch

/** Pause a queued or downloading download.
 * @param ids ids of downloads to be paused.
 * @param func Callback the paused downloads will be returned on. Note. Only downloads that
 * were paused will be returned in the result list.
 * @param func2 Callback that is called when attempting to pause downloads fail. An error is returned.
 * @throws FetchException if this instance of Fetch has been closed.
 * @return Instance
 * */
```

The problem has something to do with CallBack based on the method documentation but I can not get it to work! How can I make it fully Kotlin and call it in Kotlin?.

The library is [Fetch2](https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch) and written in Kotlin. Also I can not see whole code for the methods in the library.

Comment: Is `Func` a kotlin interface? You'll need the long & ugly `object : Func<List<String>> { override fun xyz(list: List<String>) { .. }}` syntax in kotlin to implement kotlin interfaces. The nice short lambda syntax works only for java interfaces. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions "Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported." :)

Comment: You need to create a [mcve]. You didn't specify the library, nor did you add the necessary classes/interfaces to the question, making this hard to answer without guessing.

Comment: Okay now I have added the library name and link @Zoe but I can not access all the source code.

Comment: The interface is a Java interface, so you don't need the long version (you can just use lambda). You could try forcing the parameters.

Comment: It turns out your comment is a life saver. Thanks a lot @zapl I will give you a ticket to heaven. Go and Return.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: the shortes syntax in your specific case is:

```
fetch.enqueue(requests, Func { updatedRequests ->

}, Func { error -> Timber.d("DownloadListActivity Error: %1\$s", error) })
```

---

The issue here is that you are calling function written in Kotlin. You can't use the short lambda syntax here, since Kotlin will not turn lambdas automatically into the right interface in that case.

> "Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported." (*[source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions)*)

Usually to implement (Kotlin) interfaces anonymously in Kotlin you'll have to use the full-blown object Syntax:

```
interface KFunc<T> { fun call(result: T) }

val func = object : KFunc<String> {
    override fun call(result: String) {
        println(result)
    }
}
```

However `Func` is an interface defined in Java so Kotlin offers an automatic conversion utility and you can write

```
val func: Func<String> = Func {
    result -> println(result)
}
```

This is because there is an automatically generated method for every Java interface. In this case below code is generated

```
fun <T> Func(function: (result: T) -> Unit): Func<T> {
    return object : Func<T> {
        override fun call(result: T) {
            function(result) // call the function
        }
    }
}
```

If the method that takes the `Func` was also written in Java that's where you can even leave out the `Func {}` part. E.g. given

```
public class JavaClass {
    public static void doWithFunc(Func<String> func) {
         func.call("Hello");
    }
}
```

you could write

```
JavaClass.doWithFunc { result -> println(result) }
```

However given

```
object KotlinClass {
    @JvmStatic
    fun doWithFunc(func: Func<String>) {
        func.call("Hello")
    }
}
```

you must write at least

```
KotlinClass.doWithFunc(Func { result -> println(result) })
```

On the other hand *from* Java(8+) you can use lambdas in both cases

```
JavaClass.doWithFunc(string -> System.out.println(string));
KotlinClass.doWithFunc(string -> System.out.println(string));
```

It's a little confusing. At the moment, APIs written in Kotlin that are meant for Kotlin consumption shouldn't use functional interfaces but actual function parameters, i.e. for the `enqueue` function which is

```
fun enqueue(requests: List<Request>, func: Func<List<Request>>? = null, func2: Func<Error>? = null): Fetch
```

they would ideally also offer

```
fun enqueue(requests: List<Request>, func: ((List<Request>) -> Unit)? = null, func2: ((Error) -> Unit)? = null): Fetch
```

which would allow you to call it like expected in Kotlin

```
fixedFetch.enqueue(requests, { println(it) }, { Timber.w(it) })
```

The downside is that this gives a fairly odd looking method for Java users of the library since Kotlin uses it's [`Function1`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm.functions/-function1/index.html) interface to represent function parameters. You'll also have to return `Unit.INSTANCE` since that's actually a type in Kotlin.

```
Fetch enqueue(List<? extends Request>, Function1<? super List<? extends Request>, Unit>, Function1<? super Error, Unit>)
```